# Railsで入力したグループ名が未存在なら新しいグループを、存在すれば既存のグループをユーザーに関連づけたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
- User
  - id
  - name
  - group_id

- Group
  - id
  - name
```

このようなモデルがあります。
ユーザーのフォームに「グループ名」という`テキストフィールド`を用意して、
その中にユーザーが入力したグループ名が存在すれば、そのグループとひも付けて、
存在しない場合はグループを新規作成してから紐付けるというフォームを作りたいのですが、
どのように作るのがrailsらしいのでしょうか。

ご教示お願いします。

Comment: snxpwfさんのプロフィールを見せてもらったところ、どの質問も「承認済み」になっていないようでした。もし疑問点が解決したら、一番役に立った回答を「承認済み」にしてください（緑のチェックマークを付けてください）。もし解決しなかったり、わからなかったりした場合は回答にコメントを入れてください。詳しくはこちらのヘルプをどうぞ => http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Userクラスに`group_name`という属性を追加し、before_saveでGroupを検索、なければ作成、というようにするのが良いかなと思います。

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  attr_accessor :group_name
  validates :name, presence: true

  before_save :find_or_create_group
  def find_or_create_group
    if group_name.present?
      self.group = Group.find_or_create_by!(name: group_name)
    else
      self.group = nil
    end
  end
end
```

フォームでは`User#group_name`を編集できるようにします。

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :group_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :group_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

コントローラでは`user_params`に`group_name`を追加します。
また編集画面を開いたときに、`group_name`が入力されているようにします。

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def edit
    @user.group_name = @user.group.try(:name)
  end

  # ...

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :group_name)
  end
end
```

テスト（Minitest）を書くとこんな感じです。

```
require "test_helper"

class UsersTest < Capybara::Rails::TestCase
  setup do
    Group.create!(name: 'Potato')
  end
  test "Manage users" do
    visit root_path
    click_link 'New User'
    assert page.has_selector?('h1', text: 'New User')

    # 新しいグループを作成する
    fill_in 'Group name', with: 'Tomato'
    # バリデーションエラーが起きても入力値が残る
    click_on 'Create User'
    assert page.has_content?("Name can't be blank")
    assert page.has_field?('Group name', with: 'Tomato')
    # 登録実行
    fill_in 'Name', with: 'Alice'
    click_on 'Create User'
    assert page.has_content?('User was successfully created.')
    alice = User.find_by_name('Alice')
    assert_equal 'Tomato', alice.group.name

    # 既存のグループを割り当てる
    click_on 'Edit'
    assert page.has_selector?('h1', text: 'Editing User')
    assert page.has_field?('Group name', with: 'Tomato')
    fill_in 'Group name', with: 'Potato'
    click_on 'Update User'
    assert page.has_content?('User was successfully updated.')
    assert_equal 'Potato', alice.reload.group.name

    # グループの割り当てを解除する
    click_on 'Edit'
    assert page.has_selector?('h1', text: 'Editing User')
    assert page.has_field?('Group name', with: 'Potato')
    fill_in 'Group name', with: ''
    click_on 'Update User'
    assert page.has_content?('User was successfully updated.')
    assert_nil alice.reload.group
  end
end
```

上記のコードはGithubにアップしているので、実際に動かして確認することもできます。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/find-or-create-form-sandbox

参考にしてみてください。